# Serializing array of structs containing struct containing array of strings with tpl

Tags: c, serialization, struct

I've got some code written in C with some fairly substantial structs used to hold data. I wanted to use [tpl](http://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/index.html) for serialization/deserialization of struct data for saving and loading the program's data instead of having to write a bunch of code to do it.

My problem is with the `tpl_map()` function: I can't seem to get it to parse a statement in which it would serialize an array of structs containing a struct containing an array of strings.

[tpl's documentation](http://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/userguide.html) doesn't necessarily say you can do this or that you can't do this. The thing I'd like to serialize would be described by `A(S(i$(A(s)A(s)A(s)A(s)iiiiis)sssuussi))`, but `tpl_map()` throws a parse error every time.

These are the relevant struct definitions:

```
typedef struct y {
    char** a;
    char** b;
    char** c;
    char** d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
    int h;
    int i;
    char* j;
} y_t;

typedef struct x {
    int a;
    y_t y;
    char* b;
    char* c;
    char* d;
    unsigned int e;
    unsigned int f;
    char g[40];
    char* h;
    unsigned int i;
} x_t;
```

I'm attempting to serialize an array of `x_t`.

Chopping down the tpl format string to the minimal possible and working up, I find that it doesn't seem to like having an array inside an inner struct inside an outer struct. More specifically, the problem occurs with the `A(i)` in `A(S($(A(i))))`, for instance.

Any thoughts?